# Bad interaction between a script and its tester

Tags: java

**So I have this script I've written:**

```
public class Primes {
public static void main(String[] args) {
}
//Part 4: Question 1
    public static int Binary2int(String b){
        int size = b.length();
        double count, sum=0;
        boolean binary = true;

        for (int i=0; i<b.length() ; i++){
            int digit = b.charAt(i)-'0';
            if (digit>1){
                binary = false;
                i=b.length();
            }
            count = digit*Math.pow(2, size-i-1);
            sum+=count;
        }
        if (!binary){
            System.out.println("Error - "+b+" is not a binary number.");
        }
        int sum1 = (int)sum;
        return sum1;
    }
    //Part 4: Question 2
    public static boolean isBinaryString(String b){
        boolean binary = true;

        for (int i=0; i<b.length() ; i++){
            int digit = b.charAt(i)-'0';
            if (digit>1){
                binary = false;
                i=b.length();
            }
        }
        return binary;
    }
    //Part 4: Question 3
    public static String int2Binary(int n){
        int count=0;
        if (n<=0){
            count = 1;
        }
        for (int i=n; i>0 ;){
            i=i/2;
            count++;
        }

        int arr[] = new int [count];

        for (int i=n, t=0; i>0 ;t++){
            arr[arr.length-1-t] = i%2;
            i = i/2;
        }
        if (n<=0){
            arr[0] = 0;
        }
        String s = Arrays.toString(arr);

        return s;
    }
}
```

**4.1 is meant to take a string (which stands for a binary number) and then return an integer(which stands for the integer the binary number in the input represents).
4.2 takes a binary number in the form of a string and then returns a Boolean variable (true if it’s a binary number and false if it isn’t).
4.3 is doing the opposite of 4.1, it takes an integer in the form of an integer and returns the binary number that represents it in the form of a string.
Oh and It all works fine when I'm testing it.
Now the problem is that the one checking it will be using the following (type of)script:**

```
/**
 * This class represents a tester - to be used by students to check Ex3: <br>
 * 1. call all the public functions, check compilation. <br>
 * 2. test some of function of their results. <br> <br>
 * note: for debug change the printFlag to true.
 */
public class BynaryTest {

    /**
     * if set to true - will print a trace of all the checks.
     */
    public static boolean printFlag = true;//false;
    /**
     * number of errors the test program found
     */
    public static int error = 0;

    /**
     * this main function runs the test of the EX3Tester class
     */
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        System.out.println("******* Testing Ex3 - print mode = " + printFlag + " ********");
        checkEx34();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("******* U have got " + error + " errors ********");
    }

    public static void checkEx34() {
        if (printFlag) {
            System.out.println("**** Cheking Ex21 ****");
        }
        int[] nums = {0, 1, 12345};
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i = i + 1) {
            String s = Primes.int2Binary(nums[i]);
            int num2 = Primes.Binary2int(s);
            if (nums[i] != num2) {
                error++;
                System.out.println("** Error in EX34:" + num2 + "!=" + nums[i] + " **");
            } else {
                if (printFlag) {
                    System.out.println("num[" + i + "]=" + nums[i] + " binary: " + s + " .. ok");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**The interaction between the two scripts does happen and nothing crashes, but then, for some reason, the only outcome I get from using it is:**

```
** Error in EX34:21!=0 **
Error - [1] is not a binary number.
** Error in EX34:21!=1 **
Error - [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1] is not a binary number.
** Error in EX34:21!=12345 **

******* U have got 3 errors ********
```

**I've tried to fix it myself or finding out what causes that sort of unwanted outcome but I couldn't come up with anything :(**

Comment: Um Unit test before integration test. ie Test intToBinary(5) = '101' and BinaryToInt('101') = 5. Then you can test intToBinary(5) = BinaryToInt('101'), though why it wouldn't is a puzzle...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tested it? The mistake is quite obvious if you do.

For example for 9 your `Int2Binary` method returns the following binary representation: `[1, 0, 0, 1]` as String.

Then in your `Binary2Int` you check if you only have 0s and 1s like so:

```
int digit = b.charAt(i)-'0';  // b is [1, 0, 0, 1]
if (digit>1){
   binary = false;
   //... more code ...
}
```

See the mistake now?

Comment: Not sure I get what you're trying to say, whatever the case, I get the right answers that I'd expect this script to give, it's just the tester script that causes trouble, it seems like the same error (returns 21?) in every part of it.

Comment: well think about what the part of your program that i have posted above is exactly doing with the given input. The problem is right there, you just need to figure it out ;) The tester script is not the problem! it is working as expected. Your implementation causes the problem

Comment: Take pencil and paper and check what exactly the `for` loop in your `Binary2Int` is doing with the input String `[1, 0, 0, 1]`.

Comment: Like I said, I've already tested and seen it step by step in the debugger where it gives me the answer I want. So I ran it through the debugger again just in case, what it shows is that when i=0 digit=1 which is ok, when i=1 digit=0, i=2 digit=0, i=3 digit=1, so far the Boolean variable is true and will be returned in that same way.

Comment: no I am not talking about `isBinaryString` but about the `Binary2Int` method. When i=0 you don't have digit=1, because your first char in the String is not a 1 but a `[`. Add `System.out.println(i + ": " + digit);` after `int digit = b.charAt(i)-'0';` and check again....

Comment: Your `int2Binary` is not generating Strings like `1001` but like `[1, 0, 0, 1]`

Answer (score 0):

In your method `intToBinary`, you have the following line:

```
String s = Arrays.toString(arr);
```

I think you are expecting this to take an array and concat all the values in it into a single string. Given this example:

```
int[] array = {1, 0, 0};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

You expect the output to be:

```
100
```

When in fact it is:

```
[1,0,0]
```

Comment: Are you saying that the "[" and "," etc is what causing the issue? That I'd want it to just return a string with a one number in it?
I still don't get it then, why is it when I return a Boolean value, it still gives the same error? (I think it claims that I'm returning 21 in all 3 of them?)

Comment: Take Edgar's suggestion, and use pencil and paper to check what the `for` loop in `Binary2Int` does with the input `[1, 0, 0, 1]`

Comment: Even if that for loop didn't work and gave the wrong answer back, the only two answers you can get from a Boolean variable are "true" or "false", what it seem to take from that function on the tester is just the number "21" every time, should that make sense here?